# WSO2 BAM-database other than Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, wso2, wso2-bam

Can we plug into any other database other than Cassandra , as all published data goes into Cassandra ?

Answer (score 1):

No. At the moment WSO2 BAM supports Cassandra by default. But, by extending the Stream Definition Store and Event Persistence interfaces another database can be integrated if required.